# some views are not loaded in the asp.net when connecting to sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I would like to ask what to do with this kind of problem I encountered in ASP.NET upon connecting to the SQL Server.

One view is not loaded in the solution explorer specifically the Models.

I tried to connect and disconnect but no avail.
I tried to rename the view still it wasn't loaded.

How to load this view in the application?

Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: I am the one who created the database. It has the same permission with the other views. But still it cannot be loaded. Is there something to do in the query?

Comment: Do you have `|DataDirectory|` in connection string, do you connect to the same database?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description:
"One view is not loaded in the solution explorer specifically the Models."

I would say that your vs.net project does not include the file of this view.

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't include the view.